# React social media app reverse post order

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, mongodb

I made a social media app and this is  my homepage

```
import { Box, useMediaQuery } from "@mui/material";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import Navbar from "scenes/navbar";
import UserWidget from "scenes/widgets/UserWidget";
import MyPostWidget from "scenes/widgets/MyPostWidget";
import PostsWidget from "scenes/widgets/PostsWidget";
import AdvertWidget from "scenes/widgets/AdvertWidget";
import FriendListWidget from "scenes/widgets/FriendListWidget";

const HomePage = () => {
  const isNonMobileScreens = useMediaQuery("(min-width:1000px)");
  const { _id, picturePath } = useSelector((state) => state.user);

  return (
    <Box>
      <Navbar />
      <Box
        width="100%"
        padding="2rem 6%"
        display={isNonMobileScreens ? "flex" : "block"}
        gap="0.5rem"
        justifyContent="space-between"
      >
        <Box flexBasis={isNonMobileScreens ? "26%" : undefined}>
          <UserWidget userId={_id} picturePath={picturePath} />
        </Box>
        <Box
          flexBasis={isNonMobileScreens ? "42%" : undefined}
          mt={isNonMobileScreens ? undefined : "2rem"}
        >
          <MyPostWidget picturePath={picturePath} />
          <PostsWidget userId={_id} />
        </Box>
        {isNonMobileScreens && (
          <Box flexBasis="26%">
            <AdvertWidget />
            <Box m="2rem 0" />
            <FriendListWidget userId={_id} />
          </Box>
        )}
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default HomePage;
```

and this is my post widget

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { setPosts } from "state";
import PostWidget from "./PostWidget";

const PostsWidget = ({ userId, isProfile = false }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const posts = useSelector((state) => state.posts);
  const token = useSelector((state) => state.token);

  const getPosts = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3001/posts", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
    });
    const data = await response.json();
    dispatch(setPosts({ posts: data }));
  };

  const getUserPosts = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(
      `http://localhost:3001/posts/${userId}/posts`,
      {
        method: "GET",
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
      }
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    dispatch(setPosts({ posts: data }));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isProfile) {
      getUserPosts();
    } else {
      getPosts();
    }
  }, []); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

  return (
    <>
      {posts.map(
        ({
          _id,
          userId,
          firstName,
          lastName,
          description,
          location,
          picturePath,
          userPicturePath,
          likes,
          comments,
          createdAt,
        }) => (
          <PostWidget
            key={_id}
            postId={_id}
            postUserId={userId}
            name={`${firstName} ${lastName}`}
            description={description}
            location={location}
            picturePath={picturePath}
            userPicturePath={userPicturePath}
            likes={likes}
            comments={comments}
            createdAt={createdAt} // Pass the createdAt field as a prop to the PostWidget component
          />
        )
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default PostsWidget;
```

when I post new post in my page old posts are staying on top and new posts are going below of the page how can I fix this. its my oldest [old post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExlZA.jpg) post but it is top . I use mongodb and my posts hase timestamps I want to order with timestamps

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @DreamBold yes I can and thank you. But where should I exactly put that

Comment: @DreamBold thanks for trying still same. nothing changed

Comment: @DreamBold yes I copied and past all page and posted new post too

Comment: @DreamBold yes I have

Comment: @DreamBold I did with this const reversedPosts = [...posts].reverse(); and changed post.map to  {reversedPosts.map

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse#:~:text=The%20reverse()%20method%20reverses,opposite%20to%20that%20previously%20stated. You can juse use `posts.reverse().map()`